# Multiple search in a record

Tags: r

I have a variable code in a dataset sample

```
code
asdas%4shdgjas%4hj%4
asdsadsad
fgfd%4akk
```

I want to process in such a way that when it find %4 in the variable it should assign the position of the %4 to the variable pos(for example in first records it comes at 6).after that it need to create another variable val such that it should substring the variable code from the value of pos.

Comment: so the substring for the first should be `%4shdgjas%4hj%4`?

Comment: you can take it upto two characters

Comment: What do you mean? Do the same procedure for all %4? and substring until `hj`?

Comment: Yes...based on the value of val i will do other steps

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
df <- data.frame(code=c("asdas%4shdgjas%4hj%4", "asdsadsad", "fgfd%4akk"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$pos <- sapply(gregexpr("%4", df$code, fixed = TRUE), "[", 1)
df$val <- with(df, substr(code, pos, nchar(code)))
df
#                   code pos             val
# 1 asdas%4shdgjas%4hj%4   6 %4shdgjas%4hj%4
# 2            asdsadsad  -1       asdsadsad
# 3            fgfd%4akk   5           %4akk
```

Here's an alternative for multiple matches, which may need `install.packages("tidyr")` before:

```
df <- data.frame(code=c("asdas%4shdgjas%4hj%4", "asdsadsad", "fgfd%4akk"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$pos <- gregexpr("%4", df$code, fixed = TRUE)
df <- tidyr::unnest(df)
df$val <- with(df, substr(code, pos, nchar(code)))
df
# Source: local data frame [5 x 3]
# 
#                   code   pos             val
#                  (chr) (int)           (chr)
# 1 asdas%4shdgjas%4hj%4     6 %4shdgjas%4hj%4
# 2 asdas%4shdgjas%4hj%4    15          %4hj%4
# 3 asdas%4shdgjas%4hj%4    19              %4
# 4            asdsadsad    -1       asdsadsad
# 5            fgfd%4akk     5           %4akk
```

Comment: I want to process it like, It needs to find the first occurrence and find the value of position and put val then replace it with ^^ and then find the second occurence....i want to process it like loop

Comment: Looks like an [X-Y-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) - please add the expected output data frame to your question.

Comment: Input %3Dhlct%253A1%253A16&pdtypeofsearch%3Dsearchb                               o                                                                                                                               output =Dhlct:1:16&pdtypeofsearch=Dsearchb                                                                       step one: find %25 and create a variable pos 
In this case 
pos is 8
step 2 : create a variable val such that it would extract the variable a from the pos value to two character
val is 3A
step 3 : convert the val into hexadecimal

Comment: step 4 :replace the varaible with ^^^ from the pos value to 3 characters
step 5 :replace the varaible with ^ from the pos value +3 to 2 character and concatenate with hexadecimal value

Comment: By _"please add the expected output data frame to your question"_ I asked to add it to your original question, but ... what about `URLdecode(gsub("%253A", ":", "%3Dhlct%253A1%253A16&pdtypeofsearch%3Dsearchb", fixed=T))`? This would construct your output easily.